# Change / update content of Minecraft: Pi Edition

Tags: python, minecraft, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 that came with Minecraft: Pi Edition - which is basically the Pocket Edition that you can get on the Apple App Store. I know very little when it comes to modifying Minecraft, but do have Python knowledge.

So, what I am asking here is how can I add items to the world (such as mobs or blocks)? The game is currently very limited on items, and I would like to add content, but just don't know how to go about doing this.

I don't have very much memory on the Pi, so if I can get away by using Python or something local to Raspbian - without downloading anything - that would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Raspbian installed then you should already have everything you need to start using the api and add blocks using Python.
This site is a good start for beginners https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/getting-started-with-minecraft-pi/worksheet/

For example, this code will place a stone block in front of your current position

```
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft

mc = Minecraft.create()
x, y, z = mc.player.getPos()
mc.setBlock(x+1, y, z, 1)
```

I don't believe the Pi can run the full version as it doesn't support OpenGL which the full version requires.

Comment: FYI: It can run the full version

Answer (score 1):

To run full minecraft you need to install normal desktop minecraft.

**A small guide :**

1. Install java, easiest is `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre -y` but you will have OpenJDK and not oracle java, for oracle java follow [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps).
2. Download Minecraft for Linux from the offical website (it should be a jar file)
3. Execute minecraft by double-clicking the .jar executable that is opens up the launcher.
4. Have fun
5. ???
6. Profit

Comment: Will this work on the Pi? I am really short on storage space - being my "HDD" is an 8 GB SD card. I didn't think it would have the capabilities to run the full version. I am more interested in adding the content locally and modifying it the way I would like.

Comment: @Spyder_Says_hi it will work. if you can fit java, minecraft on it it is enough. But you can't run it on ultra video settings though.

Comment: Thank you then for the information and the answer! Although, I am still wanting to edit and modify it locally.

Comment: @Spyder_Says_hi that's allright. good luck and have fun!

Comment: This answer does not solve the asked question at all. OP is asking how to modify Minecraft Pi, not how to play desktop Minecraft on a raspberry PI.

Downvoted

Comment: @MischaBehrend OP said he didn't know it was possible, i guess that's why he didn't specifically asked. That you personally don't consider this a good answer is not relevant, if you want you can [create your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) specifically asking this.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that you answer does not answer the question. The OP asked how to modify Minecraft PI. Also he said in the comments that he still wants to modify his minecraft Pi version. Which shows that OP is asking what OP is asking. And your Answer doesn't cover how to modify Minecraft pi. Btw. Your point 3 is totally invalid... you can't transform a windows executable into a jar file by just modifing the extension!

Comment: @MischaBehrend have you tried point 3? i have and it worked. Also, i considered this related for future users, if people come here in the future this may be relevant for them. If you have another answer, feel free to contribute.

Comment: I'm sure that point 3 will work. But... Oh... I see that I didn't properly formulated my argument here. I wanted to say that It is misleading. While it may work It is technically wrong. A .exe is not a .jar! If you need a .jar you can download it directly from the minecraft website. Btw. I didn't wanted to offend you. It's just that your answer isn't solving the problem in the question. But your argument "related for future users" is totally valid. Want to remove downvote!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97288/discussion-between-mischa-behrend-and-thisnamebetterbeavailable).